# how to get position pair<String, Integer> of HashMap<String, Integer>?

Tags: android

I have on my code a HashMap.
I want to get the pair of some index of the map ( like get the item X in Array .. Array[X] )

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashmaps aren't ordered so you can't get an indexed position of it. Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to use a different data structure.

If you really need to use a Hashmap, the closest thing you can do is get the key values from the Hashmap and iterate through the keyset to find what you're looking for.

```
 HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
 if(myMap.containsKey("ThingYourLookingFor")){ //Checks if that key is even in the hashmap
    for (String key : myMap.keySet()){ //Iterates through the keyList
        if(key.equals("ThingYourLookingFor")){
            //Whatever you want to do
           }
       }
    }
```

Without more details I can't guess what you're using it for, but it sounds like you might be better off using something like an ArrayList of Pairs.

```
ArrayList<Pair<String, String> myPairArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: i don't must HashMap - i need to data collection that will hold <String,Value> and i will be able to scan it

Comment: If the first value in the pair is unique and you know what that value is, then a HashMap can work and you won't have to "scan it". You can just use myMap.get(keyValue) to get the second value.

Comment: i need to scan i some cases .. for with 'foreach'